# Преобразовать цикл c BASIC на Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-basic, qbasic

Все казалось бы просто, но что то не идет в голову нормальное решение.
Код на BASIC:

```
M = 5
KTR(2 * M, 2 * M)
FOR i = 1 TO M - 1: FOR j = i + 1 TO M: KTR(i, j) = 1
```

Код на Python:

```
M = 5
KTR = [[None] * (2 * M), [None] * (2 * M)]
z = 1
z1 = z + 1
for i in range(M - 1):
    for i1 in range(M):
        KTR[0][z] = 1
        KTR[1][z1] = 1
        z = z + 1
        z1 = z1 + 1
```

Тем не менее постоянно происходит обращение за пределы списка. Подскажите что я делаю не так.
Это не школьный или университетский вопрос, у меня есть желание переделать программу на другой язык.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Буквальный перевод BASIC кода

`FOR i = 1 TO M - 1` создаёт цикл, который обходит все значения от 1 до `M-1` *включительно*.

На Питоне это можно написать как `for i in range(1, m)`. Обратите внимание `range()` не включает правую границу, поэтому оба цикла одинаковые `i` значения обходят. [E.W. Dijkstra объясняет (в 1982)](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) почему правую границу не следует включать.

`KTR(2 * M, 2 * M)` объявляет таблицу `KTR` c `2*M+1` строками и `2*M+1` столбцами (если эта конструкция работает как `DIM A(17)` конструкция, описанная в [руководстве BASIC за 1964 год](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/dartmouth/BASIC_Oct64.pdf)).

На Питоне, переменные не объявляются. Вместо этого *объекту* (к примеру списку) назначается *имя* (`ktr` в примере) с помощью знака присваивания:

```
ktr = [[None] * (2 * m + 1) for _ in range(2 * m + 1)]
```

Не смотря на то, что BASIC разрешает индексацию с нуля, к первому элементу в списке принято обращаться как `A(1)` в BASIC, а не `A[0]` как в Питоне. [Руководство](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/dartmouth/BASIC_Oct64.pdf) явно говорит, что `A(7)` это *седьмой* элемент, а не восьмой элемент как это принято в языках, где индексация начинается с нуля (`A[7]` это восьмой элемент в Питоне).

В связи с этим буквальный перевод BASIC кода на Питон:

```
m = 5
ktr = [[None] * (2 * m + 1) for _ in range(2 * m + 1)]
for i in range(1, m):
    for j in range(i + 1, m + 1):
        ktr[i][j] = 1
```

может не отражать действительные намерения программиста, писавшего BASIC код.

### Реализация [возможного] *намерения* BASIC кода

Если намерение создать верхнюю треугольную матрицу размера `m` c нулевой диагональю:

```
m = 5
ktr = [[int(i < j) for j in range(m)] for i in range(m)]
```

Здесь используется, что `True == 1` и `False == 0` в Питоне.

Или [используя `numpy.triu()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html):

```
import numpy as np

m = 5
ktr = np.triu(np.ones((m, m), dtype=int), 1)
```

#### ktr

```
[[0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

### Реализация другого [возможного] *намерения* [программиста] BASIC кода

Чтобы создать `2m x 2m` матрицу, проинициализированную нулями,  и заполнить верхнюю треугольную четвертушку над диагональю единичками:

```pay
m = 5
ktr = [[0] * (2 * m) for _ in range(2 * m)]
for i, row in enumerate(ktr[:m - 1]):
    row[i + 1:m] = [1] * (m - i - 1)
```

предполагая в вашем случае BASIC индексирует с единицы и for-to цикл обе границы включает.

Для ясности, вот то же самое, используя [numpy массивы](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html):

```pay
import numpy as np

m = 5
ktr = np.zeros((2 * m, 2 * m), dtype=int)
ktr[np.triu_indices(m, 1)] = 1
```

#### ktr

```pay
[[0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

В BASIC массив двумерный 10х10, в Python- 2х10. Конечно не будет работать.

Весь цикл в Python описать очень легко:

```
m=5
KTR = [ [0 if j<i+1 else 1 for j in range(1,m+1) ] for i in range(1,m) ]
```

Результат:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Почему-то границы массива указаны `2*M`, а перебор идет только до `M` - скорее всего это страховка от выхода за пределы массива: так любят писать те, кто пишет на BASIC.

Это, впрочем, легко поправить. Расширяем границы до `2*M` и заодно сдвигаем индексы на 1, потому что в Бэйсике первый индекс массива - 1, а не 0:

```
KTR = [[None]*2*m]+[None]+[ [None]+[0 if j<i+1 else 1 for j in range(1,m+1) ]+[0]*m for i in range(1,m) ]+[ [None]+[0]*2*m for k in range(m+1) ]
```

Результат:

```
[[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 
 [None, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [None, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [None, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Вот теперь прямо как в BASIC.

Ну и простой (но скучный) перевод как есть в Python из исходного BASIC:

```
m = 5
KTR = [ [0]*(2*m+1) for k in range(2*m+1) ]
for i in range(1,m):
    for j in range(i+1,m+1):
        KTR[i][j] = 1
```

Comment: подскажите почему при простом (скучном) переводе используются такие границы `range(1,m) | range(i+1,m+1)`. Хотя в оригинале: `FOR i = 1 TO M - 1: FOR j = i + 1 TO M` ?

Comment: @ВАНЕЧКА: "скучный" код является буквальным переводом BASIC на Python (`range(1,m)` предоставляет все значения от `1` до `m-1`), что может не отражать действительных намерений программиста. Сейчас я думаю, что намерение создать  `m x m` верхнуюю треугольную матрицу: `ktr = [[i < j for j in range(m)] for i in range(m)]` в Питоне.